# Increase numerical input in steps

Tags: labview

I want to set a numerical input to increase in steps over time. The numerical input should start at `0.2` and increase in steps of `0.2` every `60 seconds`. I have been aiming to use express vi as much as possible and am using `LabVIEW` for a `myRIO`.

Comment: What do you mean by a *'numerical input'*? An input terminal of another VI?

Comment: Following onto nekomatic's question, 'numerical input' could also mean an output terminal of a subVI. The solutions are somewhat different. Please post a picture of your code showing the problem.